# Inconsistent scope of "use strict" on different web browsers (concerning arguments.callee and caller)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

#### Situation:

I found something strange concerning **strict mode** in Javascript.

- I am using an external, third-party Javascript library which

  - was minified,
  - has over 4000 lines of code,
  - is **not** using `use strict` at all, and
  - is using `arguments.callee`.
- I am using `use strict` in my own code, scoped within a function.

When I call one of the functions provided by the library, it throws an error. However,

- the error is thrown only if I am using `use strict`
- the error is thrown in all browsers except Chrome

---

#### Code:

I've removed all the unrelated stuff and reduced the code into this ([online demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHGd4/)):

```js
// This comes from the minified external JS library.
// It creates a global object "foo".
(function () {
    foo = {};
    foo.bar = function (e) {
        return function () {
            var a5 = arguments.callee;
            while (a5) {
                a5 = a5.caller      // Error on this line in all browsers except Chrome
            }
        }
    }("any value here");
})();

// Here's my code.
(function() {
    "use strict";   // I enable strict mode in my own function only.

    foo.bar();
    alert("done");
})();
```

---

#### Test result:

```
+-----------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Browser               | OS  | Error                                                        |
+-----------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m | Win | <<NO ERROR!>>                                                |
| Opera 12.15           | Win | Unhandled Error: Illegal property access                     |
| Firefox 21.0          | Win | TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored |
| Safari 5.1.7          | Win | TypeError: Type error                                        |
| IE 10                 | Win | SCRIPT5043: Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or |
|                       |     |             arguments object is not allowed in strict mode   |
| Chrome 27.0.1543.93   | Mac | <<NO ERROR!>>                                                |
| Opera 12.15           | Mac | Unhandled Error: Illegal property access                     |
| Firefox 21.0          | Mac | TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored |
| Safari 6.0.4          | Mac | TypeError: Function.caller used to retrieve strict caller    |
+-----------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

<sup>Note: for `OS`, `Win` = Windows 7, `Mac` = Mac OS 10.7.5</sup>

---

#### My understanding:

- All modern desktop browsers support `use strict` (see [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/use-strict)).
- The `use strict` is scoped within my function, so everything defined outside its scope is not affected (see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343608/in-ecmascript5-whats-the-scope-of-use-strict)).

---

#### Question:

So, are all browsers except Chrome wrong? Or is it the other way round? Or is this undefined behaviour so the browsers may choose to implement it in either way?

Comment: Irrespective your (fascinating!) question, that loop is suspect. It's trying to access `caller` on the *function* object, which is even dodgier than accessing it on `arguments`. (Yes, some implementations did [effectively] set `caller` on function objects each time they were called, but...) If the library really does that, I'd think seriously about finding a different library.

Comment: Excellent researched and well formatted question!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: According to MDN, [`functionInstance.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) did deprecate [`arguments.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller). But you're right, that loop will fail in case of [recursion on the call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller#Notes)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am obliged to use that JS library while integrating with a third party in order to comply with their Terms & Conditions, so I guess I'll have to go with non-strict mode. Thanks for your excellent answer. Who knows what the hell they are doing with `arguments.callee` and `caller`.

Comment: I think T.J.Crowder's answer is the best you can get, but I'll just say that you really should shout at the library maker until they fix their code, since it could break with any browser update even in non-strict mode (it's using behaviour which was never standard).

Comment: @Dave: *"I'll just say that you really should shout at the library maker until they fix their code..."* Hear hear, especially if using that library is *required* for the API Pang's trying to use.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Preface

A couple of quick points before we get into the meat of this:

> - All modern desktop browsers support `use strict`...

No, not at all. <s>IE8 is a fairly modern browser</s> *(not anymore, in 2015)*, and IE9 is a <s>quite</s> fairly modern browser. Neither of them supports strict mode (IE9 supports parts of it). IE8 is going to be with us a long time, because it's as high as you can go on Windows XP. Even though XP is now flatly end-of-lifed (well, you can buy a special "Custom Support" plan from MS), people will continue to use it for a while.

> - The `use strict` is scoped within my function, so everything defined outside its scope is not affected

Not quite. The specification imposes restrictions on how even non-strict code uses functions created in strict mode. So strict mode can reach outside its box. And in fact, that's part of what's going on with the code you're using.

### Overview

> So, are all browsers except Chrome wrong? Or is it the other way round? Or is this undefined behaviour so the browsers may choose to implement it in either way?

Looking into it a bit, it looks like:

1. Chrome is getting it right one way,
2. Firefox is getting it right a different way,
3. ...and IE10 is getting it *very slightly* wrong. :-) (IE9 definitely gets it wrong, although not in a particularly harmful way.)

I didn't look at the others, I figured we'd covered the ground.

The code fundamentally causing the trouble is this loop

```
var a5 = arguments.callee;
while (a5) {
    a5 = a5.caller      // Error on this line in all browsers except Chrome
}
```

...which relies on the `caller` property of function objects. So let's start there.

### `Function#caller`

The `Function#caller` property was never defined in the 3rd edition specification. Some implementations provided it, others didn't. It's <s>a shockingly bad idea</s> *(sorry, that was subjective, wasn't it?)* an implementation issue (even more of one than `arguments.caller`), particularly in multi-threaded environments (and there are multi-threaded JavaScript engines), as well as with recursive code, as Bergi pointed out in the comments on the question.

So in the 5th edition they explicitly got rid of it, by specifying that referencing the `caller` property on a strict function would throw an error. (This is in [§13.2, *Creating Function Objects*, Step 19](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2).)

That's on a *strict* function. On a non-strict function, though, the behavior is unspecified and implementation-dependent. Which is why there are so many different ways to get this right.

### Instrumented Code

It's easier to refer back to instrumented code than a debugging session, so let's [use this](http://jsbin.com/ejijiw/1):

```
console.log("1. Getting a5 from arguments.callee");
var a5 = arguments.callee;
console.log("2. What did we get? " +
            Object.prototype.toString.call(a5));
while (a5) {
    console.log("3. Getting a5.caller");
    a5 = a5.caller;      // Error on this line in all browsers except Chrome
    console.log("4. What is a5 now? " +
                Object.prototype.toString.call(a5));
}
```

### How Chrome Gets It Right

On V8 (Chrome's JavaScript engine), the code above gives us this:

```
1. Getting a5 from arguments.callee
2. What did we get? [object Function]
3. Getting a5.caller
4. What is a5 now? [object Null]
```

So we got a reference to the `foo.bar` function from `arguments.callee`, but then accessing `caller` on that non-strict function gave us `null`. The loop terminates and we don't get any error.

Since `Function#caller` is unspecified for non-strict functions, V8 is allowed to do anything it wants for that access to `caller` on `foo.bar`. Returning `null` is perfectly reasonable (although I was surprised to see `null` rather than `undefined`). (We'll come back to that `null` in the conclusions below...)

### How Firefox Gets It Right

SpiderMonkey (Firefox's JavaScript engine) does this:

```
1. Getting a5 from arguments.callee
2. What did we get? [object Function]
3. Getting a5.caller
TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored
```

We start out getting `foo.bar` from `arguments.callee`, but then accessing `caller` on that non-strict function fails with an error.

Since, again, the access to `caller` on a non-strict function is unspecified behavior, the SpiderMonkey folks can do what they want. They decided to throw an error if the function that would be returned is a strict function. A fine line, but as this is unspecified, they're allowed to walk it.

### How IE10 Gets It Very Slightly Wrong

JScript (IE10's JavaScript engine) does this:

```
 1. Getting a5 from arguments.callee 
 2. What did we get? [object Function] 
 3. Getting a5.caller 
SCRIPT5043: Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode
```

As with the others, we get the `foo.bar` function from `arguments.callee`. Then trying to access that non-strict function's `caller` gives us an error saying we can't do that in strict mode.

I call this "wrong" (but with a *very* lower-case "w") because it says that we can't do what we're doing in strict mode, but we're not *in* strict mode.

But you could argue this is no more wrong that what Chrome and Firefox do, because (again) the `caller` access is unspecified behavior. So the IE10 folks decided that their implementation of this unspecified behavior would throw a strict-mode error. I think it's misleading, but again, if it's "wrong," it certainly isn't *very* wrong.

BTW, IE9 definitely gets this wrong:

```
1. Getting a5 from arguments.callee 
2. What did we get? [object Function] 
3. Getting a5.caller 
4. What is a5 now? [object Function] 
3. Getting a5.caller 
4. What is a5 now? [object Null]
```

It allows `Function#caller` on the non-strict function, and then allows it on a strict function, returning `null`. The spec is clear that that second access should have thrown an error, as it was accessing `caller` on a strict function.

### Conclusions and Observations

What's interesting about all of the above is that in addition to the clearly-specified behavior of throwing an error if you try to access `caller` on strict functions, Chrome, Firefox, and IE10 all (in various ways) prevent your using `caller` to get a reference to a strict function, even when accessing `caller` on a non-strict function. Firefox does this by throwing an error. Chrome and IE10 do it by returning `null`. They all support getting a reference to a **non**-strict function via `caller` (on a non-strict function), just not a strict function.

I can't find that behavior specified anywhere (but then, `caller` on non-strict functions is entirely unspecified...). It's probably the Right Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>, I just don't see it specified.

This code is also fun to play with: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/iliguq/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/iliguq/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Strict and Loose Function#caller</title>
  <style>
    p {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin: 0.1em;
    }
    .err {
      color: #d00;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function display(msg, cls) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        if (cls) {
            p.className = cls;
        }
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }

    // The loose functions
    (function () {
      function loose1() {
        display("loose1 calling loose2");
        loose2();
      }
      loose1.id = "loose1"; // Since name isn't standard yet

      function loose2() {
        var c;

        try {
          display("loose2: looping through callers:");
          c = loose2;
          while (c) {
            display("loose2: getting " + c.id + ".caller");
            c = c.caller;
            display("loose2: got " +
                    ((c && c.id) || Object.prototype.toString.call(c)));
          }
          display("loose2: done");
        }
        catch (e) {
          display("loose2: exception: " +
                  (e.message || String(e)),
                  "err");
        }
      }
      loose2.id = "loose2";

      window.loose1 = loose1;

      window.loose2 = loose2;
    })();

    // The strict ones
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      function strict1() {
        display("strict1: calling strict2");
        strict2();
      }
      strict1.id = "strict1";

      function strict2() {
        display("strict2: calling loose1");
        loose1();
      }
      strict2.id = "strict2";

      function strict3() {
        display("strict3: calling strict4");
        strict4();
      }
      strict3.id = "strict3";

      function strict4() {
        var c;

        try {
          display("strict4: getting strict4.caller");
          c = strict4.caller;
        }
        catch (e) {
          display("strict4: exception: " +
                  (e.message || String(e)),
                 "err");
        }
      }
      strict4.id = "strict4";

      strict1();      
      strict3();
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am forced to use non-strict mode to workaround the error, which is no good for development. I guess I am disappointed by the browsers, or rather, disappointed by the ECMAScript 5 spec.

Comment: @Pang: I understand, although I think really it's the library that's letting you down. That's one seriously dodgy bit of code. :-)

Comment: @Pang: Why are you forced to use `.caller` at all?

Comment: @Bergi 'coz [I'm forced to use that function which I didn't write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871050/inconsistent-scope-of-use-strict-on-different-web-browsers#comment24337960_16871050).

Comment: @Pang: FWIW, I had a chance to come back and go into detail about `Function#caller`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder almost every time I see T.J.Crowder's sign in the question list I know the answer will be much longer and I will learn much more than expected. And my quess was filled again :) thank you.

Comment: The error messages are definitely confusing. I almost started to lose sanity when trying to discern what's going on after seeing the error. Opera seems the most reasonable of them all. Btw, a simplified example like this — `function foo() { arguments.callee.caller } (function() { "use strict"; foo() })()` — is enough to reproduce this anomaly.

Comment: On the other hand, it could be that the clause from 15.3.5 is the culprit, if interpreted differently: _Function instances that correspond to strict mode functions (13.2) and function instances created using the Function.prototype.bind method (15.3.4.5) have properties named “caller” and “arguments” that throw a TypeError exception. **An ECMAScript implementation must not associate any implementation specific behaviour with accesses of these properties from strict mode function code**._ Are we talking about _direct_ access from strict mode code? Or indirect, like in the above example? :)

Comment: @kangax: LOL! At one point not only did I have that quote in there, but I had actually boldfaced exactly that part of it. Great minds. But I took it out because of the *"...from strict mode function code."* which seems to take it out of the picture (as this access is clearly from non-strict function code). But again, that line made me wonder as well...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your *very comprehensive* answer. Learnt a lot from you. Gotta +1 before you edit it so many times that it'll turn into a community wiki.

Comment: It seems that Chrome gets it still wrong. For `'use strict';function t_1() {var c = arguments.callee;} t_1();` it correctly throws a TypeError, but for `'use strict';function t_0() {var c = arguments.caller;} t_0();` it just returns `undefined`. It seems that is incorrectly treats `arguments.caller` for strict functions, too.

Answer (score 3):

I have to use an older Telerik JS library that I cant't readily update and encountered this error this morning.  One possible workaround for some people might be to use the 'setTimeout' JS function to leave strict mode before calling the loose mode function.

e.g.  Change this:

```
function functionInStrictMode(){
  looseModeFunction();
}
```

To something like this:

```
function functionInStrictMode(){
    setTimeout(looseModeFunction);      
}
```

I'm guessing this probably works because setTimeout reverts the context to the global namespace and/or leaves the scope of functionInStrictMode.  I don't fully understand all the particulars.  There might be better ways; I did not research this thoroughly, but I thought I'd post it here for discussion.