# Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, gwt

Am calling an modal dialog done using GWT[*legacy code] from my angular js code;

And this modal dialog works/pops-up in all the browsers except IE10/9 and IE 10, I get this error

> "Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is
>   not allowed in strict mode"

After debugging a bit more using IE debugger I found that angular.min.js is using "use strict" which most of other library also uses; 
Removing the use strict makes the popup to appear in IE10; But to that is not feasible solution;

Even after debugging a bit more for exact line where this error is caught in the anuglar.min.js code!

```
$apply:function(a){try{return m("$apply"),this.$eval(a)}catch(b){e(b)}
```

Angular also provides [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) and [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) but not able to know exactly how to overcome this situation;

And my situation is almost similar to one mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871050/inconsistent-scope-of-use-strict-on-different-web-browsers-concerning-argumen)

*Legacy Code: Currently have to re-write entire modal dialog using angular but its not done and using dialog method, as its part of module;